# Postgres 9.5 foreign table inheritance not using indexes

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5, inheritance, foreign-data, postgresql-performance

In PostgreSQL 9.5.0 I have a partitioned table that collects data by months. I tried to use the new PostgreSQL feature of foreign table inheritance and pushed one month of data to another PostgreSQL server, so I got a foreign table. When I run my query from the primary server, the query takes 7x longer to execute than on the server where I have the foreign table. I am not passing a lot of data by network, my query looks like:

```
explain analyze
SELECT source, global_action, paid, organic, device, count(*) as count, sum(price) as sum
FROM "toys"
WHERE "toys"."container_id" = 857 AND (toys.created_at >= '2015-12-02 05:00:00.000000') AND
(toys.created_at <= '2015-12-30 04:59:59.999999') AND ("toys"."source" IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY "toys"."source", "toys"."global_action", "toys"."paid", "toys"."organic", "toys"."device";

HashAggregate  (cost=1143634.94..1143649.10 rows=1133 width=15) (actual time=1556.894..1557.017 rows=372 loops=1)
   Group Key: toys.source, toys.global_action, toys.paid, toys.organic, toys.device
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1143585.38 rows=2832 width=15) (actual time=113.420..1507.373 rows=76593 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on toys  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=242) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: ((source IS NOT NULL) AND (created_at >= '2015-12-02 05:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2015-12-30 04:59:59.999999'::timestamp without time zone) AND (container_id = 857))
         ->  Foreign Scan on toys_201512_new  (cost=100.00..1143585.38 rows=2831 width=15) (actual time=113.419..1488.445 rows=76593 loops=1)
 Planning time: 2.990 ms
 Execution time: 1560.131 ms
```

**Does PostgreSQL use indexes on foreign tables?** (I have indexes defined in the foreign table.) If I run the query  directly on that server, it takes 200ms.

Here is parent table definition:

```
Table "public.toys"
id bigint
job_reference character varying(100)
container_id integer
user_token character varying(1000)
user_ip character varying(100)
user_zip character varying(10)
user_agent character varying(2000)
url_referrer character varying(2000)
page_url character varying(2000)
source character varying(100)
action integer
created_at timestamp without time zone
cpa numeric(9,3) not null default 0.0
duplicate boolean not null default false
fingerprint character varying(255)
email character varying(1000)
mobile_email_apply boolean
country character varying(255)
country_matched boolean
device integer
organic boolean
job_seeker_id character varying(255)
applicant_status integer
ats_applicant_status character varying(255)
ats_applicant_source character varying(255)
price numeric(9,4)
job_group_id integer
analytic_source character varying(255)
global_action integer
paid_organic integer
paid boolean
meta text
params character varying(2000)
analytic_associated_click_id bigint
external_id character varying(100)
associated_click_id bigint
cpc numeric(9,3)
Indexes:
    "job_stats_master_pkey1" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Child table has check constraint:

```
"toys_201512_new_created_at_check" CHECK (
    created_at >= '2015-11-30 19:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND
    created_at <  '2015-12-31 19:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Inherits: toys
```

And indexes on:

```
"toys_201512_new_analytic_source" btree (analytic_source)
"toys_201512_new_country" btree (country)
"toys_201512_new_created_at" btree (created_at)
"toys_201512_new_duplicate" btree (duplicate) WHERE duplicate = false
"toys_201512_new_container_id" btree (container_id)
"toys_201512_new_container_id_created_at" btree (container_id, created_at)
"toys_201512_new_fingerprint" btree (fingerprint)
"toys_201512_new_global_action" btree (global_action)
"toys_201512_new_id" btree (id)
"toys_201512_new_job_group_id" btree (job_group_id)
"toys_201512_new_job_reference" btree (job_reference)
"toys_201512_new_on_country_matched" btree (country_matched) WHERE country_matched = true
"toys_201512_new_on_cpa" btree (cpa) WHERE cpa <> 0::numeric
"toys_201512_new_on_duplicate_and_country_matched" btree (duplicate, country_matched) WHERE duplicate = false AND country_matched = true
"toys_201512_new_on_mobile_email_apply" btree (mobile_email_apply) WHERE mobile_email_apply = true
"toys_201512_new_source" btree (source)
"toys_201512_new_user_ip_user_agent" btree (user_ip, user_agent)
"toys_201512_new_user_token" btree (user_token)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Postgres can use indexes on the foreign server.** But there are quite a few more obstacles than for local tables. Read the chapter [Remote Query Optimization](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/postgres-fdw.html#AEN171694) in the manual.

[Comments in the **current source code** of `postgres_fdw.c`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/postgres__fdw_8c_source.html) are revealing, too:

```
521  * [...] For a foreign
522  * table, we don't know what indexes are present on the remote side but
523  * want to speculate about which ones we'd like to use if they existed.
...
675      * need to be a bit cautious here.  It would sure be nice to have a local
676      * cache of information about remote index definitions...
...
722      * corresponds to SeqScan path of regular tables (though depending on what
723      * baserestrict conditions we were able to send to remote, there might
724      * actually be an indexscan happening there).
```

#### Index

This index of yours looks good for it:

```
"toys_201512_new_container_id_created_at" btree (container_id, created_at)
```

If you have *many* NULL values you might even make that a partial index by appending `WHERE source IS NOT NULL`, making the index look even better for the Postgres query planner.

### Statistics for query planning

Make sure the query planner can work with **valid statistics**. The numbers in your `EXPLAIN` output show quite a mismatch:

```
Foreign Scan on toys_201512_new  (cost=100.00..1143585.38 rows=2831 width=15)
                           (actual time=113.419..1488.445 rows=76593 loops=1)
```

27x as many rows as Postgres expected were actually returned . [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/postgres-fdw.html#AEN171585)

> Running [`ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/sql-analyze.html) on the foreign table is the way to update the local
>   statistics; this will perform a scan of the remote table and then
>   calculate and store statistics just as though the table were local.
>   Keeping local statistics can be a useful way to reduce per-query
>   planning overhead for a remote table — but if the remote table is
>   frequently updated, the local statistics will soon be obsolete.

Since accessing foreign tables is potentially expensive / delicate, this does not happen automatically. **Foreign tables are not covered by autovacuum.** [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/sql-analyze.html#AEN73376)

> Foreign tables are analyzed only when explicitly selected.

If the remote table changes a lot, you might want to activate **`use_remote_estimate`**. [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/postgres-fdw.html#AEN171585)

> This option, which can be specified for a foreign table or a foreign server, controls whether `postgres_fdw` issues remote `EXPLAIN` commands to obtain cost estimates. A setting for a foreign table overrides any setting for its server, but only for that table. The default is `false`.

Finally, test to see what is actually sent to the foreign server:

> The query that is actually sent to the remote server for execution can
>   be examined using `EXPLAIN VERBOSE`.

#### Query

Your query decluttered and formatted, with one minor improvement:

```
SELECT source, global_action, paid, organic, device
     , count(*) AS count, sum(price) AS sum
FROM   toys
WHERE  container_id = 857
AND    created_at >= '2015-12-02 05:00:00'
AND    created_at <  '2015-12-30 05:00:00'
AND    created_at <= '2015-12-30 04:59:59.999999'
AND    source IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY source, global_action, paid, organic, device;
```

Simpler, cleaner and also matches your `CHECK` constraint better and avoids possible corner case problems.

Comment: Great answer. But I have a simple query that joins two foreign tables with a few filters, and it's not using indexes that queries on the local database would use even after I `ANALYZE`d both of them (which took a long time). One table is a billion rows, and the other is millions. Maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: @sudo: I suggest you start a new question to present all relevant information for your case. Comments are not the place. You can always link to this one if it helps to make your case clear.